# Computer micro-freezing then hanging up when playing some games

Tags: freeze

I have had this problem for years: When I play some video games, my computer starts to freeze for very short time periods including the following:

- the audio output stutters
- the video output freezes
- the mouse hangs
- keyboard keys can't be pressed or keep active after there pressed and released
- microphone problems

This is getting worse unless I close the game and if it is not stopped it ends in constant audio stutter and either a frozen image which will not change or a bluescreen: "A clock interrupt was not received on a
secondary processor within the allocated time interval".

Comment: Does this persist through clean installations of the OS? Have you ever overclocked your machine?

Comment: I would start with all the basic hardware diagnostics.  Run a Hard Drive diag, and a RAM diag.  Just to make sure.  There is nothing more frustrating than to diagnose a problem for hours, just to find out that the hard drive is bad.

Comment: If you have altered any memory timings or speed as well as bus or CPU speeds and power throughput, you should post that as well.  Then again, you said `I have had this problem for years` which means it might be time to upgrade...

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames I did RAM testing and HD test, also changed my HD a while ago.

Comment: @Michael Yes and yes, but not currently.